# Mocking out methods defined in external Golang module

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking

With this code in an external Go file/module:

```
type ErrorHandler = func(*ExternalContext) error

type Config struct {
    errorHandler: ErrorHandler
}

type ExternalContext struct {
...
}

func (e *ExternalContext) ExternalFuncOne() some_return {
    ...
}

func (e *ExternalContext) SendStatus (status int) error {
    ...
}
```

My code:

```
func errorCallback(ctx *ExternalContext) error {
    ...
    some logic
    ...
    result = ctx.ExternalFuncOne()
    if result == 2 {
        some logic
    } else if result == 3 {
        some different logic
    }
    return ctx.SendStatus(some_variable)
}

main() {
    // Call the external module's new struct creation function.
    ExternalNew {
        Config {
            ErrorCallback: errorCallback
        }
    }
}
```

Based on the block of example code, how can I mock out 'ExternalFuncOne' and 'SendStatus' methods in my unit testing?
I work for a medical device company and I have to achieve as close to 100% code coverage. It's easiest for me to mock third-party methods so I can instrument whatever return I choose to for branch testing.

Comment: You cannot mock concrete types in Go (as opposed to interface types), so if you cannot change ErrorHandler to accept an interface you also cannot replace ExternalContext.

Comment: In addition to Peter's comment, I think you should make an interface at your code. The interface has methods you need at `ExternalContext`
And then you can mock struct implementing the interface and use it at its unit test.

Answer (score 0):

I think xgo is exactly created for this scenario.
Check https://github.com/xhd2015/xgo for more details.
As for your question, here is the solution:

```golang
func errorCallback(ctx *ExternalContext) error {
    setupMock(ctx)
    ....
}

func setupMock(ctx *ExternalContext){
     mock.Mock(ctx.ExternalFuncOne,func(...,results){
        results.GetFieldIndex(0).Set(1)
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: creator of the xgo project after years of diving into go compiler.